# How to simulate the click on Submit-button by using the 'browser.find_element_by_class_name'?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The source code of the page look like as bellow:

```
<div class="inner1">
    <!--<h4>LOGIN:</h4>-->
    <div class="SubID" style="float:left; margin-left:30px;">
      <label for="ID">Your <span class="subscriberID">Subscriber ID</span>:</label>
      <br>
      <input name="ID" size="34" maxlength="20" type="text" style="width:233px !important;">
    </div>
    <div class="SubName">
      <label for="LASTNAME">Your <span class="lastName">Last Name</span> OR <span class="lastName">Company</span>:</label>
      <br>
      <input name="LASTNAME" size="34" maxlength="50" type="text" style="width:233px !important;">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="" />
    <div class="SubButton1 spaceBelow">
      <input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    <p class="spaceBelow Clear" style="text-align:center;">The above
      information can be obtained from your magazine label.<br>
      A sample label is shown below.</p>
    <p class="spaceBelow Clear" style="text-align:left;"><a href="idlookup.asp">Forgot
        your Subscriber ID?</a></p>
</div>
<!--END INNER1 -->
```

I can simulate the entering of 'SubID' and 'SubName' as bellow:

```
user_name = browser.find_element_by_class_name('SubID > input[type="text"]')
user_name.send_keys(user)
password = browser.find_element_by_class_name('SubName > input[type="text"]')
password.send_keys(pwd)
```

I use the following code to simulate the clicking pf the Submit button but it was failt:

```
submit = browser.find_element_by_class_name('"SubButton1 spaceBelow" > input[type="submit"]')                                                  
submit.click()
```

I got error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Given css selector expression "."SubButton1 spaceBelow" > input[type="submit"]" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: '."SubButton1 spaceBelow" > input[type="submit"]' is not a valid selector: "."SubButton1 spaceBelow" > input[type="submit"]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
submit = browser.find_element_by_name("submitbtn")                                                  
submit.click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You already submitted the answer but you can also use XPaths:

```
submitBtn = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='submitbtn']")                                                  
submitBtn.click()
```

Hope it helps you!